# close websocket stream connection?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

How can I close this websocket connection?/what I'm i doing wrong here with this code?

```
var conn;

function connect_mtgox() {
    conn = io.connect('http://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox');
    conn.on('message', function (data) {
        last_price = (data.ticker.last.value_int);
    });





}

function stop_mtgox()

{

    conn.close();

}
```

Links:
mtgox API https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming

Thanks

Comment: That's a local variable.  It doesn't exist outside the function.

Comment: oops, my mistake, but even when I change that it still don't work.

Comment: What's wrong? What happens? How & when are you calling that?

Comment: I have it on a button click that call a functions and in that function  it call the stop_mtgox function and after that it should do a jquary animation but it "freezes" on stop_mtgox function and don't move on to the animation, I can comment out the conn.close(); and just do like an window.alert and that works fine and all the animations, so something is wrong with the conn.close() I'm not really sure thats how you close a websocket connection.

Comment: Check your JS console.

Comment: This is what I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object#<c> has no method 'close'"

Comment: That's a Perl module.

Comment: oh no wonder It was confusing.